# WCF CORS issue - WPF application successfully connects but Angular App throws 405

Tags: wcf, rest, cors

I have a question about enabling cross-domain calls.

I have a WCF Rest service that is hosted in xyz domain. I am able to test these REST APIs from Advanced Rest Client, Postman and Fiddler. I also have a WPF application that actively calls these API which is hosted in a different domain (say abc domain) which works fine in getting responses.
However, when I created a new Angular web application and a Windows Service (deployed on abc domain), and tried calling the APIs from these two components, I am getting a 405 error.

Can someone explain:

1. How REST clients always are able to successfully establish a connection?
2. How does my WPF successfully connects to the WCF service even though
   its on a different domain?
3. Why is my Windows Service/Web App not able to talk to WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the issue here is caused by the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). The browser issues this `OPTIONS` verb request to ask the server if the [origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is allowed to call the API in a non-safe manner.

If your WCF REST service does not deal with this request, the WCF runtime will try to dispatch the request to your service implementation.
However, if the runtime does not find a method to call for this verb, it will return a `405 Method Not Allowed` response.

I've dealt with this in the past by using an [IOperationInvoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ioperationinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation, installed via an [IOperationBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.ioperationbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx). This [article](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html) describes a slightly different way of doing basically the same.